# Sharing a drive on a hosted Win2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, file-sharing

I have a dedicated windows 2003 server that is hosted in a data center.  I would like to map the drive to my pc - and looking for the best way to do that.  I could create a VPN, but that seems like overkill?  I have created the same login/pw.

Is there a simpler way than creating a VPN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an ingenious little hack to do a "drive mapping" over an SSH tunnel. It doesn't scale well for multiple remote hosts, but if you're looking at "mapping a drive" to a single remote host and have SSH access into your remote network it might do what you need:

> [Map a Network drive (net use) over
>   SSH](http://www.neophob.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/103-Map-a-Network-drive-net-use-over-SSH.html)

Otherwise, I'd recommend using a VPN. If you're not partial to the Microsoft VPN technologies, think about using OpenVPN (http://www.openvpn.org). Some helpful links for OpenVPN:

- Official HOWTO - http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html
- Static key mini-HOWTO (not recommended for security, but easy to get up and running quickly) - http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html

Comment: i love tunneling with ssh either under cygwin or dropping an old laptop/tower on the network and tunneling with localhost and net stop server. i think the article above covers that. but right now vista and windows 7 breaks support for port 139 so i don't know of a work around.gd

Comment: i meant dropping an old computer and putting like ubuntu lts server edition on it and enabling ssh.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Terminal Services to connect to your server? If so you can enable local drive mapping then from the TS session on the server you can see the drive on your PC.

JR

Comment: In my experience TS fileshares are painfully slow, ymmv :)

Comment: SMB is very slow over a WAN link, whether it's a conventional VPN or a TS redirected drive. There isn't a lot that can be done about that.

Comment: I've found the TS remote client drive mapping feature to be horribly, violently unreliable. So much so that I won't use it with Customers.  @John: The TS remote client drive mapping RDP virtual channel protcol actually isn't SMB either. It's yet another networked filesystem protocol that Microsoft has come up with, and it has its own bag of issues. Having said that, SMB is excruciating over a WAN, too.

Answer (score 2):

i would say hamachi, install as a service and at log on.
then you can use unc path \ip_of_hamachi_machine or \netbios_name_chosen_hamachi_install

i would say a secure approach is better than just having pptp or something that can be comprimised.
gd

Comment: Why is using PPTP not a "secure approach"? It seems like using a strong password and 128-bit encryption with PPTP would probably be "good enough" for most cases. Any software system can "be compromised" if it's configured poorly. Do you think that LogMeIn Hamachi is bug-free?

Comment: can you set pptp to send the password encypted? if so then i take it back but i always thought it was send in the clear so it can be sniffed with a man in the middle, i remember testing this with cain and once the arp was poisoned you were able to see the password?

Comment: You can use EAP-TLS with PPTP starting with Windows 2000 Server. PPTP could, in theory, be configured to use plaintext authentication, but more than likely what you saw was cryptanalysis of the highly insecure MS-CHAP protocol.

Comment: yup i think it was ms-chap proto. thanks.gd

Answer (score 0):

You could use webfolders, If I remember correctly, you can map using "net use" to an http:// address.  I don't think it works out of the box with https, but i've read that stunnel is a suggested work around.